# Fetch live data from SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm writing a small Python script which needs to fetch live data from a database (I'm using SQLite 3 for now). I may reuse this function for a lot of scripts. Can this code be made better?

```
def fetch_database(database, table, filter_dict, case=None):
    """
    Takes filter parameter as a dict
    dict = {'column_name':['filter', 'filter2'], 'column_name2'=[], ..}
    case = wrap around the dictionary key(UPPER, LOWER, etc..), None
    database (with pathname ex: database.db
    table
    column = dict.keys()
    """

    conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
    c = conn.cursor()
    filter_dict = dict_format(filter_dict) # A separate function deletes empty keys from dictionary
    keys_list = filter_dict.keys()
    statement = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table
    if len(keys_list) > 0:
        statement += ' WHERE '
        for keys in keys_list:
            if case == None:
                key = keys
            else:
                key = case + '(' + keys + ')'
            temp_data = filter_dict[keys]
            temp_size = len(temp_data)
            if keys_list.index(keys) != 0:
                statement += ' AND '
            if temp_size > 0:
                for data in temp_data:
                    if temp_data.index(data) == 0:
                        statement += key + '="' + data + '"'
                    else:
                        statement += ' OR ' + key + '="' + data + '"'
    dataset = c.execute(statement)
    dataset = dataset.fetchall()
    return dataset
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it comes to SQLite, I like to first wrap everything related to database into its own class:

```
class SqliteDB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        self.db_path = os.path.join(self.parent_directory, 'db.sqlite3')
        self.db_connection = sqlite3.connect(self.db_path)
        self.db_cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()

    def execute(self, query, args=''):
        return self.db_cursor.execute(query, args)

    def commit(self):
        self.db_connection.commit()

    def close(self):
        self.db_connection.close()
```

That way, you can easily use the class into whatever project you need. Now, given the above, you can modify your function to take advantage of the new class:

```
def fetch_database(database, table, filter_dict, case=None):
    filter_dict = dict_format(filter_dict)
    keys_list = filter_dict.keys()
    statement = 'SELECT * FROM {}'.format(table)
    if len(keys_list) > 0:
        statement += ' WHERE '

        for keys in keys_list:
            if case is None:
                key = keys
            else:
                key = '{}({})'.format(case, keys)

            temp_data = filter_dict[keys]
            temp_size = len(temp_data)

            if keys_list.index(keys) != 0:
                statement += ' AND '

            if temp_size > 0:
                for data in temp_data:
                    if temp_data.index(data) == 0:
                        statement += '{}="{}"'.format(key, data)
                    else:
                        statement += ' OR {}="{}"'.format(key, data)

    return database.execute(statement).fetchall()
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    database = SqliteDB()
    fetch_database(database, 'some_table', {'some': 'dict'}, case=None)
```

---

Other changes that I did to what you had:

- I've used the `.format()` method instead of the deprecated `+` method
- I've modified `if case == None` to `if case is None`.
- I added [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard

Comment: seems like you should have mentioned how this is prone to sql injection attacks

Comment: ([Its it is](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Its-and-It%27s) - first sentence.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks. I know the difference. It was just a typo

Answer (score 11):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned the **code being vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**:

[image: Her daughter is named Help I'm trapped in a driver's licence factory.]

<sup>([XKCD source](http://xkcd.com/327/))</sup>

Using string formatting and string concatenation to construct SQL queries is, first of all, *unsafe* and also, *fragile* - you will have to handle the argument types, balancing and escaping quotes yourself manually.

Instead, you should *parameterize* your queries - this way, you are not only protected from SQL injections, but also let the database driver worry about the python-to-database type conversions, sample:

```
query = """
    SELECT column1 
    FROM table
    WHERE column2 = ?"""
cursor.execute(query, (data, ))
```

Note how parameters are passed in a separate argument to `execute()`.

On the other hand, it feels like you may be reinventing the wheel in a certain way - please check if switching to an ORM like [`SQLAlchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or [`peewee`](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee) would help to avoid re-writing boilerplate code.

Comment: I wanted to say this, because I remembered I've even given an answer to [a related question here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134504/inserting-robot-moves-into-an-sqlite3-database/134507#134507) but I don't know why I didn't do it ^_^. Nicely spot!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning SQLAlchemy, I will check that. The user input is spell corrected (using personnel dictionary), classified & hence a dictionary format for filtering. It can't contain anything that is not listed.

Comment: @MrGrj but you've still provided a very nice SQLite db Python wrapper! I've decided to add Bobby Tables's story here too :) Thanks.